# Match two data frames by two columns and extract values from third column

Tags: r

I apologize if is a basic or duplicate question, but I am a beginner R user.

I am attempting to match every row in Dataframe A by Sex and Age to the two corresponding columns in Dataframe B. I know there will be a match for sure, so I want to extract values from the matching rows of two different columns in Dataframe B and store them in Dataframe C.

```
Dataframe A                          Dataframe B

ID   Sex   Age   Weight            Row  Sex  Age   X1    X2
1     1    24    36                1    1    24   18.2  12.3
2     1    34    56                2    2    87   15.4  16.5
3     2    87    12                3    1    64   16.3  11.2 
4     2    21    08                4    2    21   15.6  14.7
5     1    64    33                5    1    34   17.7  18.9 
...


Dataframe C
ID   Age   Sex  Weight   Y1   Y2
1     1    24    36     18.2  12.3
2     1    34    56     17.7  18.9           
3     2    87    12     15.4  16.5           
4     2    21    08     15.6  14.7          
5     1    64    33     16.3  11.2
```

There are 9000 IDs in my dataframe. I've looked at similar questions like this one

[Fill column values by matching values in each row in two dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176171/fill-column-values-by-matching-values-in-each-row-in-two-dataframe)

But I don't think this I am applying this code correctly. Will a for loop be useful here?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ID){
    dfC[i,Y1] <-df2[match(paste(dfA$Sex,dfa$Age),paste(dfB$Sex,dfB$Age)),"X1"]

   dfC[i,Y2] <-df2[match(paste(dfA$Sex,dfa$Age),paste(dfB$Sex,dfB$Age)),"X2"]
}
```

I know the merge function was also suggested, but these two variables are not actually named the same way in my data set.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not rename the variables so that names of the keys match? If it's really a problem, use the by.x and by.y keys from merge.

Comment: When I try this, I lose about 700 observations. I'm not sure the reason for this as every age and sex variation in DFA should have corresponding age and sex values in DFB. Would it matter if the variables in DFB are "factors" while the variables in DFA are "num"?

Comment: Add all=TRUE to your merge call and you can see for yourself what the issue is. I don't think it should matter what the type of non-key variables is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro... reduce function in R for such operations

```
set.seed(1)
list.of.data.frames = list(data.frame(id=1:10, sex=1:10 , age =1:10 , weight=1:20), data.frame(row=5:14, sex=11:20 , age :1:20 , x1:1:10, x2:1:10), data.frame(id=8:14, sex=11:20 , age :1:20 ,weight:20:30, y1:1:10, y2:1:10))
merged.data.frame = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), list.of.data.frames)
tail(merged.data.frame)
```